# react on android Studio where is device manager

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, reactjs, react-native

I am beginner with android and React 
When I installed the node.js and create project with react 
I tried to open it with android studio , what I already need to open the 
device manager which was available before , but now I can't lunch it
as Image , please help

[image]

Comment: try running `android avd` from console

Comment: How can I do that ?, Sorry I am  new

Comment: See the bottom of the Android Studio window where is says "Terminal". Type in there

Comment: @cricket_007 it refuse to write in there

Comment: Strange... It should let you. Then open a command prompt / terminal window for your operating system instead

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access it from **Tools**->**Android**->**AVD Manager**.
I suspect you may have inadvertently removed it from the Toolbars. If this is the case, then perhaps you want to restore it. You can `Right-Click` on the Toolbar and select **Customize Custom Menus and Toolbars...**. Then select Restore Default, then try again (see if you can now see AVD Manager on the Toolbar.

Comment: you're right I can't access TOOLS>android 
what shall I do after custom menus?

Comment: Just to be sure, are you able to access it through Tools>Android-AVD Manager?

Comment: I updated the answer - you can Right-Click on the Toolbar, select Customize Custom Menus and Toolbars.... Then select Restore Default. Also you might want to restart Android Studio (though I doubt if this is necessary)

Comment: Thanks you very much for your precious time , you put me on the way, my problem was about I installed plugin by wrong way and then I uninstall it and it worked fine now